# Do I have to avoid appending for performance?

Tags: arrays, performance, go, slice

I am new to Golang.
Should I always avoid `append`ing slices?

I need to load a linebreak-separated data file in memory.
With performance in mind, should I count lines, then load all the data in a predefined length array, or can I just append lines to a slice?

Comment: There are good profiling tools included with go. You'll see appending is good enough so that it's usually the fastest solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should stop thinking about performance and start measuring what the actual bottleneck of you application is.

Any advice to a question like "Should do/avoid X because of performance?" is useless in 50% of the cases and counterproductive in 25%.

There are a few really general advices like "do not needlessly generate garbage" but your question cannot be answered as this depends a lot on the size of your file:

- Your file is ~ 3 Tera byte? Most probably you will have to read it line by line anyway...
- Your file has just a bunch (~50) of lines: Probably counting lines first is more work than reallocating a `[]string` slice 4 times (or 0 times you you `make([]string,0,100)` it initially). A `string` is just 2 words.
- Your file has an unknown but large (>10k) lines: Maybe it might be worth. "Maybe" in the sense you should measure on real data.
- Your file is known to be big (>500k lines): Definitively count first, but you might start hitting the problem from the first bullet point.

You see: A general advice for performance is a bad advice so I won't give one.

Comment: Also, append super sekretly doubles the underlying array size for small arrays and multiplies by about 1.5x for big arrays when the underlying memory is used up, so it's not like it's calling realloc every time.

Comment: Jsor's comment should be included in the answer, because it _is_ general.
append is not O(n), it's amortised O(1), which means there is virtually no reason to avoid it, ever.

Comment: Ahhh dammit. That's implementation specific, not part of the specification.